# Draw Circular rings around Arc points - VTK UnstructuredGrid

Tags: graphics, geometry, computational-geometry, vtk

I am trying to create circular rings aroung arc points. I'm trying to create a Cylinderical bend between two points. For this I have done Following:

1. Draw an ARC between two points. For that, I have 2 Diagonal points in 3D space, I used that points to find Square vertices and used one of the square point as center point to draw an ARC between two diagonal points.

```
def draw_square_from_diagonal_points(point1, point2):
    # Extract coordinates of the two diagonal points
    x1, y1,z1 = point1
    x2, y2,z2 = point2

    # Find the midpoint of the diagonal
    mx = (x1 + x2) / 2
    my = (y1 + y2) / 2

    # Calculate the difference vector between point1 and the midpoint
    dx = x1 - mx
    dy = y1 - my

    # Find the fourth corner point of the square
    bx = mx + dy
    by = my - dx

    # Define the four points of the square
    pointA = (x1, y1)
    pointB = (bx, by)
    pointC = (x2, y2)
    pointD = (mx - dy, my + dx)  # The fourth corner opposite to pointB
    return pointD
```

```
def draw_arc(radius , center,num_points=16,circle_radius=1, cross_sections_radius = 0.5, circle_points=8):

    radian_angle = 2 * math.pi / num_points
    arc_points = []
    circle_pts = []
    for i in range(num_points):
        if i == num_points/4 + 1:
            break
        cal_angle = i * radian_angle
        xx = center[0] + radius * math.cos(cal_angle)
        yy = center[1] + radius * math.sin(cal_angle)
        zz = center[2]
        arc_points.append([xx,yy,zz])
return arc_points
```

Following is the illustration of the above code.
[Illustraction of drawing ARC by finding the Center point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFMis.png)

Now the Question is **HOW TO DRAW circular Rings Point around these ARC points**? These Points should be in that direction that **if we join those circular Rings Points, It would form a Cylinderical Bend Like structure like below:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8wJK.png)

I tried the following code to draw the circular points around arc points and it actually draws but the orientation of the points are not good.
Code:

```
def add_spherical_points(center, radius):
    
    phi_angle = math.pi / 6 #60 Angle
    circular_points = []
    newpts=[]
    for i in range(12):
        delta_angle = 2 * math.pi * i / 12
        #angle = i * delta_angle
        x = center[0] + radius * math.sin(phi_angle) * math.cos(delta_angle) 
        y = center[1] + radius * math.sin(phi_angle) * math.sin(delta_angle)
        z = center[2] + radius * math.cos(phi_angle)
        circular_points.append([x,y,z])

    return circular_points
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TPJl.png)

Answer (score 0):

OK, to make circle around point on the large circle arc, you need to calculate some vectors.

Normal vector to the plane of the large circle. Seems in your case that plane is parallel to OXY plane (and you are using `zz = center[2]`), so normal is `n=(0,0,1)`, but in general case you have to get cross product of two square (ABCD) sides

```
n = (AB x BC).normalized
```

Now unit vector from the large circle center to current arc point. In your case it is `vr = (math.cos(cal_angle), math.sin(cal_angle))`, in general case expression will be more complex (depends on predefined data)

Having these two vectors, you can make points

```
large_arc_point + r*n*cos(delta_angle) + r*vr*sin(delta_angle)
```

Comment: Bundle of thanks for your detailed answer @MBo. The Circle Center is the ARC point itself. I'm using it as the center of the circle and then generating **12 points** around it in circular rings but obviously, there are some direction vectors that need to be calculated. I'm a newbie in the Computer Graphics domain so have very little understanding of it. Could you please refer me to any helpful article regarding this?

Comment: `The Circle Center is the ARC point itself` yes, I see, you want to make small circles perpendicular to large arc to make something like donut piece. What part of answer is hard? [Large article about cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)